# Why some attributes become missing after a Python object is pickled and reloaded?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I encountered a problem that some attributes of an instance become missing after I dumped the instance to a pickle file and loaded it back. Can anyone help to explain? Thanks!

Here is a concrete example:

```
File/directory hierachy:
-test
 -test_module
  -__init__.py
  -myDataFrameMapper.py
  -mySklearn.py
 -main.py
```

__init__.py:

```
from .mySklearn import mySklearn
```

mySklearn.py

```
import sklearn_pandas as sk_pd
from .myDataFrameMapper import myDataFrameMapper

class mySklearn:
      def initialize():
          sk_pd.DataFrameMapper.myTransform = myDataFrameMapper.transform()
```

myDataFrameMapper.py

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper

class myDataFrameMapper:

      def transform():
          def closure(self, df, **kwargs):
                 self.addedKey = 'addedValue' # a new attribute is added here
          return closure
```

main.py

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import random
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder

from test_module import mySklearn

mySklearn.initialize()

data = {'pet':["cat", "dog", "dog", "fish", "cat", "dog", "cat", "fish"],
        'children':[4., 6, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4],
        'salary':[90, 24, 44, 27, 32, 59, 36, 27]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

column_tuples = [
   ('pet', LabelEncoder()),
   ('children', LabelEncoder()),
   ('salary', LabelEncoder())
]

mapper = DataFrameMapper(column_tuples, input_df=True)
mapper.fit(data)

print('original attributes in mapper:')
print(mapper.__dict__)

mapper.myTransform(df.iloc[[1]])

print('\nafter adding a new attributes \'addedKey\':')
print(mapper.__dict__)

print('\ndump the mapper into a pickle file...')
picklefile = open('mapper.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(mapper, picklefile)
picklefile.close()

print('\nload the mapper from the pickle file...')
picklefile = open('mapper.pkl', 'rb')
mapper1 = pickle.load(picklefile)
picklefile.close()

print('\nafter being loaded, the attributes in the mapper are:')
print(mapper1.__dict__)
```

After running `python3 main.py`, we observe the following outputs:

```
original attributes in mapper:
{'built_default': False, 'sparse': False, 'input_df': True, 'df_out': False, 'features': [('pet', LabelEncoder()), ('children', LabelEncoder()), ('salary', LabelEncoder())], 'default': False, 'built_features': [('pet', LabelEncoder(), {}), ('children', LabelEncoder(), {}), ('salary', LabelEncoder(), {})], 'transformed_names_': []}

after adding a new attributes 'addedKey':
{'built_default': False, 'addedKey': 'addedValue', 'sparse': False, 'input_df': True, 'df_out': False, 'features': [('pet', LabelEncoder()), ('children', LabelEncoder()), ('salary', LabelEncoder())], 'default': False, 'built_features': [('pet', LabelEncoder(), {}), ('children', LabelEncoder(), {}), ('salary', LabelEncoder(), {})], 'transformed_names_': []}

dump the mapper into a pickler file:

load the mapper from the pickle file:

after being loaded, the attributes in the mapper are:
{'built_default': False, 'sparse': False, 'input_df': True, 'df_out': False, 'features': [('pet', LabelEncoder(), {}), ('children', LabelEncoder(), {}), ('salary', LabelEncoder(), {})], 'default': False, 'built_features': [('pet', LabelEncoder(), {}), ('children', LabelEncoder(), {}), ('salary', LabelEncoder(), {})], 'transformed_names_': []}
```

We can see that the attributes `'addedKey': 'addedValue'` became missing when the mapper was loaded back from the pickle file.

Comment: Can you provide a fully reproducible example? When I create `Mapper` myself and add `key3` during runtime, I get the expected outcome. (After un-pickling I see all three keys).

Comment: I suspect you're working with some sort of ORM framework. You're going to need to specify which one, and what classes are involved. Basically, we need a [MCVE].

Comment: @SyntaxVoid sorry for the confusion. I edited my question by providing a concrete working example. Please check again and let me know if you have any clue.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for the suggestion. I updated the question with a working example, please try and see whether you can reproduce the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper` has a custom [`__setstate__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__) method, to attempt to maintain pickle compatibility with pickles created on older versions. ([Here's](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/sklearn-pandas/blob/08ed9d02b1e1cb8ac97b1f4c44aa04831675ffa8/sklearn_pandas/dataframe_mapper.py#L154) the 1.8.0 version of the method.) This `__setstate__` is responsible for restoring the state of an unpickled instance, and it completely ignores your added attribute.

Pickle implementation customization is one of the reasons trying to add your own attributes to other people's classes is usually a bad idea.

Comment: \_\_setstate\_\_ extracts the values from `state` and applies them to the attributes, can you point out where the value of `state` was set?

Comment: @QiZhang: The data ultimately comes from the `__dict__` of the originally pickled instance, though this is also customizable.